# How to arrange multiple panels

Tags: java, swing

How can i do this in java i can't set size to my textfield i don't know how exactly do that How the result must be:

[image]

and this is output of my code i must add 2 more labels and texfields after id and first textfield Mine:

[image]

```
class IU extends JFrame{
public IU(){
    super("Tabela mysql");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JToolBar myBar=new JToolBar();
    getContentPane().add(myBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JButton btnFirst=new JButton();
    JButton btnPrevious=new JButton();
    JButton btnNext=new JButton();
    JButton btnLast=new JButton();
    JButton btnAdd=new JButton();
    JButton btnEdit=new JButton();
    JButton btnDelete=new JButton();
    JButton btnSearch=new JButton(); 
    JButton btnUndo=new JButton();
    JButton btnSave=new JButton();

    JTextField txtAfis=new JTextField();

    btnFirst.setIcon(new ImageIcon("MoveFirst.png"));
    btnPrevious.setIcon(new ImageIcon("MovePrevious.png"));
    btnNext.setIcon(new ImageIcon("MoveNext.png"));
    btnLast.setIcon(new ImageIcon("MoveLast.png"));
    btnAdd.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Add.png"));
    btnEdit.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Edit.png"));
    btnDelete.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Delete.png"));
    btnSearch.setIcon(new ImageIcon("find.jpg"));
    btnUndo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("undo.jpg"));
    btnSave.setIcon(new ImageIcon("save.jpg"));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JTextField t = new JTextField();
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
    t.setSize(100, 20);

    t1.setBounds(20,10,70,20);
    t2.setBounds(20,10,70,20);


    JLabel label = new JLabel("Nume");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Prenume");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Id");

    getContentPane().add(panel);


    panel.add(label3);
    panel.add(t, BorderLayout.EAST);

    panel1.add(label2);
    panel1.add(t1);
    panel2.add(label);
    panel2.add(t2);

    myBar.add(btnFirst);
    myBar.add(btnPrevious);
    myBar.add(txtAfis);
    myBar.add(btnNext);
    myBar.add(btnLast);
    myBar.add(btnAdd);
    myBar.add(btnEdit);
    myBar.add(btnDelete);
    myBar.add(btnSearch);
    myBar.add(btnSave);
    myBar.add(btnUndo);
    add(panel);

    }
}
```

Comment: First image is my output second image i want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a text field use:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

The number will allow the text field to determine a size for itself. In the above case it will hold 10 "W" characters.

Then you use layout managers to get your desired layout.

Comment: Can you explain a little how desire with layout

Comment: @GeorgeSendrea, Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand how each layout manager works. Based on your picture you might want to use a GridBagLayout (more flexible, but more complicated) or you could wrap a GridLayout on a panel with a FlowLayout and then add this panel to the frame. The only way to learn layout managers is to download the demo code and play with it.